# Issue with requests in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I created an API using django restframework. It works well on the django development server. When the application is migrated to a web server (apache mod wsgi, nginx - gunicorn) it works fine only if the pagination is set to 100 records per page, if the pagination is set to more than 100 records, requests between 100 and 200 records They remain stalled or blocked.

I deployed the application in Apache with wsgi and gunicorn with nginx. But the problem persists.
It works perfect on the django development server with any page size and works well on the server if I set the page size to 100 records.

View

```
class SoftwareList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = SoftwareModel.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = SoftwareSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('product_type',)
```

Model

```
class SoftwareModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    product_type = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    software_suggestion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'software_view'
```

Serializer

```
class SoftwareSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SoftwareModel
        fields = ('id', 'product_id', 'product_type',
                  'software_suggestion')
```

Settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

Expected: The request with a pagination different than 100.

Actual: Request Stalled/Blocking

Comment: Can I see your model and serializer? it appears to be `timeout` issue caused by making a lot of queries.

Comment: Sure, the question is updated.

Answer (score -1):

Not enough rep to comment...

Sounds like an optimization issue with the number of queries. Are you making use of [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for following foreign key fields?

You can also install [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to count the number of queries when in debug mode and using `rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer`

Comment: No, I'm not using select_related () or prefetch_related (). I'll verify those methods and see what is happening. Thanks for the help.